# OFFSET last non-blank cell in row

Tags: offset

I have a table with incomplete cells.

I need to return three pieces of information in three separate cells all on the same row.

I've tried to show the basics of the data in the image below and the desired result.

I've been able to find a formula for the last non-blank cell on a row. However, I cannot off set it to pick the penultimate, and the left of the penultimate.

Formulas to using INDEX and COUNTA fail, when the rows are not fully filled in from Columns A through to the last non-blank.

Can you help?

[Raw data table in cells A1:L5, with desired results in cells A7:L11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWn4K.png)

Comment: In addition, I can confirm that each set of data comes in three (this is a code, followed by a name, followed by a title). The problem with my attempts using COUNTA are when there is no preceding set of three in columns A:C.

Comment: SOLVED?    I believe I have found a way around this, but wonder if any experts could review it and offer a more elegant formula.     I can locate the last non-blank cell in a row, using the formula =LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:I2<>""),A2:I2).   I have then managed to use INDEX and MATCH rather than OFFSET to find the penultimate non-blank cell and return the relevant TEXT. I do this by using the following: =INDEX(A2:I2,MATCH(LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:I2<>""),A2:I2),A2:I2,1)-1). In order to return the value in two cells to the left of the last non-blank, I change "-1" to "-2" at the end of the formula.